# Navigation Host Fragment is overwriting destination fragment on previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying fragment transaction using navigation host fragment, but on navigating to the destination fragment the old fragment is still visible on screen like fragment added on one another.

Here is my code:

some_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/some_nav"
app:startDestination="@+id/WelcomeFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/WelcomeFragment"
    android:name="com.example.ui.fragment.WelcomeFragment"
    android:label="WelcomeFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_WelcomeFragment_to_secondFragment"
        app:destination="@+id/secondFragment"
         />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
    android:name="com.example.ui.fragment.SomeFragment"
    android:label="secondFragment">
</fragment>
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/all_navigation_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/some_nav"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

WelcomeFragment.kt

```
button.setOnClickListener{
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_WelcomeFragment_to_secondFragment)
    }
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate")
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
host = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.all_navigation_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment? ?: return
    navController = host.navController
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        val dest: String = try {
            resources.getResourceName(destination.id)
        } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
            Integer.toString(destination.id)
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Navigated to $dest")
        var toolBarText = R.string.title
        when (destination.id) {
            R.id.WelcomeFragment -> toolBarText = R.string.title
            R.id.secondFragment -> toolBarText = R.string.button
        }
        setupToolbar(toolBarText)
    }
}
```

Why is it overwriting on one another ? did i miss anything obvious?

Comment: Can you include all of your `onCreate()` method in your Activity? Do you do any `FragmentTransaction` (i.e., `beginTransaction()`) in that method?

Comment: @ianhanniballake i have updated MainActivity.kt and activity_main.xml please check..

Comment: there is no fragment transaction in it